# How do you set the formating of axis labels via secondary_yaxis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

How do you set the formatting of axis labels via [`secondary_yaxis`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.secondary_yaxis.html)?

In the example below, I'd like to have more control of the second axis labels (e.g. format='%g'). I think it should be possible to pass something like `ticklabel_format` or `format` as kwargs, but neither seems to work (both raise `AttributeError: 'SecondaryAxis' object has no property ...`).

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np

    # Conversion functions to and from km and hPa
    def km2hPa(input):
        return np.exp( input / -7.6 ) * 1013.

    def hPa2Km(input):
        return -7.6 * np.log( input  / 1013. )

    # Fake data to plot
    Y = np.linspace(1000, 100, 100)
    X = np.array( [i**2 for i in np.linspace(0, 10, len(Y)) ] )

    # Plot up data with both primary (hPa) and secondary axis (km)
    plt.close('all')
    kwargs = {} # Add a format specifier here?
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    plt.plot(X, Y)
    ax.set_ylabel('Pressure altitude (hPa)')
    ax.invert_yaxis()
    secax = ax.secondary_yaxis('right', functions=(hPa2Km, km2hPa), **kwargs)
    secax.set_ylabel('Altitude (km)')
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

secax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.StrMethodFormatter("{x:g}"))
```

or

```
secax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FormatStrFormatter("%g"))
```

[image]